# More robust than sed for find and replace

Tags: linux, bash, sed

I need to replace some strings in a file programatically. As a minimum case, I'm showing here just replacement for `|FNAME|` and `|LNAME|`.

Currently I am using this for the task:

```sh
sed -e "s/|FNAME|/$FNAME/g" -e "s/|LNAME|/$LNAME/g"
```

The problem is that *somebody* is my list is going to have a `/` in their name or address or something. So instead I use `@` as the delimiter. And don't you know somebody uses `@` in their last name. One person actually, legitimately has a backtick in their name, and their first name isn't Robert.

What is a more robust way to perform this fixed string find-replace without having to pick a fragile delimiter?

Comment: Can you add example data?

Answer (score 1):

The secret is to escape any slash characters in the variable contents:

```sh
fname_esc=${FNAME//\//\\\/}
lname_esc=${LNAME//\//\\\/}

sed -e "s/|FNAME|/$fname_esc/g" -e "s/|LNAME|/$lname_esc/g"
```

A demo:

```sh
$ cat file
Hello |FNAME|-|LNAME|
$ FNAME="first/name" LNAME="last/name"
$ fname_esc=${FNAME//\//\\\/}
$ lname_esc=${LNAME//\//\\\/}
$ sed -e "s/|FNAME|/$fname_esc/g" -e "s/|LNAME|/$lname_esc/g" file
Hello first/name-last/name
```

Using a different `s///g` delimiter reduces the "leaning toothpick" syndrome a bit:

```sh
sed -e "s,|FNAME|,${FNAME//,/\\,},g" -e "s,|LNAME|,${LNAME//,/\\,},g"
```

---

Other options: both of these pass the replacement strings to the program via command-line options. This way, the program can treat them as plain strings. However, both of these use more advanced regular expressions so the pipes
need to be escaped.

- perl

  ```sh
  perl -pse 's/\|FNAME\|/$fname/g; s/\|LNAME\|/$lname/g' -- -fname="$FNAME" -lname="$LNAME" file
  ```
- awk

  ```sh
  awk -v fname="$FNAME" -v lname="$LNAME" '{
      gsub("\\|FNAME\\|", fname)
      gsub("\\|LNAME\\|", lname)
      print
  }' file
  ```